# Prove/Disprove that this is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ space

Tags: normed-spaces

Let's suppose that $\left \| * \right \|_{2}$ is any norm on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ space. And we define $\left \| * \right \|_{3}$ as a mapping: $\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, such that for every vector $ x=\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\ 
x_{2}\\ 
x_{3}
\end{pmatrix}$ :

$\left \| x \right \|_{3}= \left \| \binom{x_{2}}{3x_{1}} \right \|_{2}+37\left \| \binom{x_{2}-x_{3}}{x_{2}} \right \|_{2}$

And I need to *prove or disprove* that $\left \| * \right \|_{3}$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ space.
So I've already proved that $\left \| x \right \|_{3}\geq 0$ and $\left \|\alpha  x \right \|_{3}=\left | \alpha  \right |*\left \| x \right \|_{3}$ for every x from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. But I have a problem with triangular inequality $\left \|\ x+y \right \|_{3}\leq \left \| x \right \|_{3}+\left \| y \right \|_{3}$. May be I can see it somehow on the matrix of this mapping? Or may be I should disprove it someway.

Comment: isn't it pretty straight forward? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

If $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, then
$$\|x+y\|_3  = \left\|{x_2+y_2 \choose 3(x_1+y_1)} \right\|_2 + 37 \left\|{x_2-x_3+y_2-y_3 \choose x_2+y_2}\right\|_2.$$

Now just apply the triangle inequality with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm.